# Making a CSS shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I was trying to make a CSS shape like this[image: this icon]. I need to make exact the shape shown in the attached image. How to make this?
Please help.

Fiddle link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/u05hn51r/)

**CSS**

```
#activityIcon {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50% / 10%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: .1em;
}
#activityIcon:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: -5%;
  left: -5%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 5% / 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if my answer provides anything that kougiland's doesn't, but I did it so I figured I might as well post it.

It looks like this.

[image]

[Here's the codepen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jDrhH)

The HTML looks like this.

```
<div class="tab-bar">
  <div class="tab">&utrif;</div>
  <div class="tab">&utrif;</div>
  <div class="tab">&utrif;</div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this.

```
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.tab-bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab {
  margin: 0 1.55rem;
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.1rem;
  width: 9rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  background-color: #666;
  transform: perspective(4rem) rotateX(-20deg);
  border-radius: 0 0 1rem 1rem;
}

.tab::before,
.tab::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  top: -1rem;
  border-color: #666;
  border-style: solid;
}

.tab::before {
  left: -1rem;
  border-radius: 0 2rem 0 0;
  border-width: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
}

.tab::after {
  right: -1rem;
  border-radius: 2rem 0 0 0;
  border-width: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Very nice, +1 for a modern approach. Personally I'd go with this, however since it doesn't work on IE9 and below, it may or may not meet the OP's needs.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

## [UPDATE...](http://jsfiddle.net/u05hn51r/4/)

[image]

MARKUP:

```
<div id="activityIcon">
    <div class=concaveTop></div>
    &utrif;
</div>
```

STYLE:

```
#activityIcon {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background:#757575;
    border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
    margin:40px auto;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
#activityIcon:before,#activityIcon:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}
#activityIcon:before{
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 81px solid #757575;
    left: -18px;
}
#activityIcon:after {
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 81px solid #757575;
    right: -18px;
}
.concaveTop:before, .concaveTop:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 34px;
    height: 32px;
}
.concaveTop{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 314px;
    height: 28px;
    left: -50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 -4px 0 #757575;
}

.concaveTop:before{
    left: 1px;
    box-shadow: 20px -24px 0 3px #757575;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.concaveTop:after{
    right: 15px;
    box-shadow: -18px -24px 0 3px #757575;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u05hn51r/2/)

MARKUP:

```
<div id="activityIcon">
    &utrif;
</div>
```

STYLE:

```
#activityIcon {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background:#333;
    border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
    margin:40px auto;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
#activityIcon:before,#activityIcon:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}
#activityIcon:before{
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 81px solid #333;
    left: -18px;
}
#activityIcon:after {
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 81px solid #333;
    right: -18px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks pretty close, I am also trying to make the concave curve at the top but it is not working.